# stringByEvaluatingJavaScript to press button

Tags: web, swift3, ios10

Im using the `webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript()` function to enter some data into a website using this code:

```
self.webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementsByTagName(\"input\")[2].value = \"usename\"")  //enters username
self.webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementsByTagName(\"input\")[3].value = \"pass\"")  //enters password
self.webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementsByTagName(\"input\")[5].submit") //press button?
```

The first 2 commands work fine, and enter the information into the website, the last command is meant to press the Login button, but I can't get it to work.  I have tried quite a few different commands, but nothing worked.
The html of the button and fields is:

```
<input type="text" class="large-12" id="username" name="username" value="" required="">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<label for="username">Membership Number</label>
<input type="password" class="large-12" id="password" name="password" value="" required="">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://www.webname.org/">
<input type="submit" name="login" id="submit" value="Login" class="button small login">
```

What do I need to do to 'press' the button programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem.  Solution:

```
self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('submit').click()")
```